# How to give IcoMoon icons a fixed width?

Tags: fonts

I know that Font Awesome has the [class "fa-fw"](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons) for fixed width icons. How would I accomplish this with IcoMoon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to css rules of 'base' `i` or `.icon` (depending on your font generation settings):

```css
display: inline-block;
width: 1.25em;
text-align: center;
```